# how do i create a toolbar that changes its style when you scroll down the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

why does this approach not work? am i missing something? is there a better way to do this entirely?

html:

```
<div id="evrth">
    <div id="bar">
        <div id="container">
            <div>something</div>
            <div>something</div>
            <div>something</div>
            <div>something</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("evrth").onscroll = function() {scroll1()};

function scroll1() {
    const scroll = document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
    scroll.classList.add("postcontainer");
}
```

i tried to use every type of scroll detection function and it still doesn't work

Comment: Ok so you're adding `postcontainer` class to `innerHTML` (it's a string) not to the element. Consider removing it. Good luck

Comment: this did not work, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To detect scroll on the page, you can to listen to the `scroll` event on `window` and pass your callback there. From there you could use `window.pageY` to get the number pixels scrolled.

Here's an example. Try scrolling inside the window and see color of the toolbar change.

```js
const toolbar = document.querySelector('.toolbar')
const windowHeight = window.innerHeight

function map(value, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  return (value - x1) * (y2 - x2) / (y1 - x1) + x2
}
  
function onScroll() {
  const green = map(window.scrollY, 0, windowHeight, 0, 255)
  toolbar.style.background = `rgb(255, ${green}, 127.5)`
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
onScroll() // Set color at least once
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 200vh;
}

.toolbar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar"></div>
```